# How can I use the MYSQL BIT_COUNT function through nhibernate/fluent nHibernate?

Tags: mysql, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm doing some voodoo, and need to order my results by a bit_count operator using c#/linq/fluent-nhibernate.

here's my current order statement:

```
orderby m.InitiatorInventory & wanted descending
```

What I really want is something like this

```
orderby BIT_COUNT(m.InitiatorInventory & wanted descending)
```

This is the Mysql function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#function_bit-count

Comment: Do you want a MySQL statement?

Comment: No, The answer from binaryHowl nails it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use `CreateSQLQuery` or you can register your own `BIT_COUNT` dialect in NHibernate:

```
public class MyDialect : MySqlDialect
{
    public MyDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction("bit_count", new StandardSQLFunction("bit_count", null));
    }
}
```

More information [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/registering-freetext-or-contains-functions-into-a-nhibernate-dialect.aspx).

Comment: Definately going to try this out.

Comment: so i did it inline, not as good but..
           if (connectionType.Contains("MySql"))
            and then used 'CreateQuery' to make the sql with bit_count